# Checking and array for two diffrent pairs

Tags: javascript

I want to check an array with length 5 for two different pairs, and if two pairs exist add them up. My thought process is this:

1. Sort the array.
2. If the first and second, or second and third position in the array are the same, add their values to a new array, and remove them from the first array.
3. Start over and do the same thing again, but only add the next pair, if its not equal to the first pair.
4. If the length of the second array is 4, sum up the array. If the length is not 4, the original array didnt contain two diffrent pairs.

Here is the code i came up with:

```
/*temp is the array i test, it's just an array with length 5 
filled with random integer values.*/
var score = 0;
var scoreArray = new Array();
var flag = 0;
/*My thought is, that's it's only necessary 
to check the first two position to find a pair, 
as the array only has a length of 5. */
for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
    if(temp[i] == temp[i+1] && flag != temp[i]){
        flag = temp[i]
        scoreArray.push(temp[i], temp[i+1]);
        temp.splice(i, 2);
        i = -1;
    }
}
if(scoreArray.length == 4){
    for(i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++){
        score += scoreArray[i];
    }
}
```

If I find two pairs in my array i go out of bounds in the for-loop on the last run-through, but I can't figure out how to resolve this.

Comment: do you have some examples and the wanted results?

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand the question very well, but I suspect you can use 
.map() or .filter() methods to achive what you want

.map() loops through the array and returns new array, so you can check and modify each element with this method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

.filter() scans through the array, and return a new array of elements that passed the scan criteria:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

For example this is something with .map() method:

```
const temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(temp);

// loop through temp array to populate new array
const updatedTemp = temp.map(element => {
    // if element have this value
  if (element === 1 || element === 2) {
      // do something to it
    return (element += 1);
  }
  // else just return the element
  return element;
});
// console.log the results
console.log(updatedTemp);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You forgot checking when you are done, and thus after finding two pairs, the loop starts checking for a third one, indexing out of the remaining array (which has 0 or 1 element at that time).

```js
function getScore(temp){
  temp.sort();
  var scoreArray = [];
  var flag = 0;
  for(i = 0; i <= 1 && scoreArray.length < 4; i++){
    if(temp[i] == temp[i+1] && flag != temp[i]){
      flag = temp[i]
      scoreArray.push(temp[i], temp[i+1]);
      temp.splice(i, 2);
      i = -1;
    }
  }
  var score = 0;
  if(scoreArray.length == 4){
    for(i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++){
      score += scoreArray[i];
    }
  }
  return score;
}

function test(){
  var arr=inp.value.split(" ").map(x => parseInt(x));
  if(arr.length===5 && !isNaN(arr[4]))
    res.innerText=getScore(arr);
  else
    res.innerText="Type 5 numbers with 1-1 space between them";
}

test();
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text" oninput="test()" onchange="test()" value="1 2 3 2 1"><br>
<div id="res"></div>
```